# Optimal 2D Tile rendering in C#

Tags: c#, image, graphics, system.drawing

So I'm making a simple 2D Sidescrolling game in C# however I've found that using Graphics.drawImage doesn't particularly allow me to update the tiles as I wish. For example, I tell it to draw the image and it stays where I tell it to be. I want to be able to move the entire scene left to right. This would be easier if I had to use a for loop or something and define it's position every time it draws the image.

This may be confusing and I'm certain there's a way of doing it, I just don't know how.

So my question to you is: How can I control the positioning of each rectangle drew on a form so that I can scroll the entire scene to the left when I wish?

Comment: 5 seconds of Googling: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/114/entry-1049-scrolling-an-image-in-c%23/

Comment: what platform are you using? WPF? WinForm (this looks more likely because you mentioned ``Grpahics.DrawImage``)? XNA?

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly no game/graphics expert, so take this with a grain of salt.

A couple things spring to mind.

First, you could pre-render the entire level as one bitmap, then just paint the relevent portion into your picturebox.

Second, the Graphics class has a Transforms property (I may have the name wrong).  You could add a linear transformation to the graphics object so the painting coordinates of your tiles wouldnt change, but the graphics object would slide, or I think the graphics term is "translate" the output en-masse.